# Running notebooks in parallel on Databricks

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm a Databricks user and I'm trying to run multiple notebooks in parallel within a parent notebook. This is what I have so far

```
from typing import Dict, List
from functools import partial
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

from ranker.config import Config


def run_notebook(value, notebook_path: str = None,
                 params: Dict[str, str] = None, property: str = "department"):
    dbutils.notebook.run(notebook_path, -1, {**params, **{property: value}})


def run_parallel(notebook_path: str,
                 params: Dict[str, str],
                 property: str = "department",
                 values: List[str] = Config.departments,
                 max_workers: int = 2):
    """
    Runs the same notebook with the same parameters for all input departments
    """
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        results = executor.map(partial(run_notebook,
                                       notebook_path=notebook_path,
                                       params=params,
                                       property=property), values)
    # This is to make sure that an Error is returned if one (or both) of the notebooks fail to run
    for result in results:
        assert result is None
```

And the script that runs the notebooks in parallel is

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
test_start_date = date(2020, 11, 23)
n_test_days = 7
test_dates = []
for n_day in range(n_test_days + 1):
    test_dates.append((test_start_date + timedelta(days=n_day)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
    
print(test_dates)

run_parallel("./my_notebook", params, "test_date", test_dates, 2)
```

Everything works great and the notebooks do run in parallel, but the problem is that I would like to limit to only 2 runs at a time. In the above examples this means that I want two notebooks with two different `test_date` to run in parallel until the list of all possible `test_dates` have been run. I thought that `max_workers` would do the trick, but I was wrong. Any idea how to improve this?

Comment: Why not put the run_parallel line in the loop that creates 2 dates at a time instead of collecting all the dates?